# Backbone View creates Favorites Pane

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

But it looks like it is getting to big.

How can I break this up into smaller pieces?

In general this seems messy and I'm trying to make it more readable.

```
/******************************************************************************************************************(120)
** BVFave
** - renders favorites using underscore templates
**
**
*/

    var BVFave = Backbone.View.extend({
        Name: 'BVFave',
        path: $A.Reg.get('path_favicons'),
        E: {},
        initialize: function () {
            this.ns = this.el.id + '_';
            this.addArc();
            this.el_arcmarks = $A.el('#' + this.el.id + '_arcmarks');
            this.el_tags = $A.el('#' + this.el.id + '_tags');
            this.tags = {};
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
        },

        addArc: function (){
            if (this.id) {
                var arc_string = '' + this.composeArc(this.id);
                var arc_string1 = '' + this.composeArcTop(this.id);

                this.el_fave_hold = $A.el('#fave_hold');
                this.el_arc_hold = $A.el('#arc_hold');

                $A.appendHTMLAsElement(arc_string, this.el_fave_hold);
                // $A.appendHTMLAsElement(arc_string1, this.el_arc_hold);
                this.el = $A.el('#' + this.id);
            } else {
            }
        },
        render: function () {
            var tag_string = '',
                page_string = '',
                current_id,
                previous_id;
            this.obj = this.collection.toJSON();

            // parse the json data
            _.each(this.obj, function (val) {
                previous_id = current_id;
                current_id = this.ns + val.tag;
                if ((previous_id !== current_id) || (previous_id === undefined)) {
                    this.tags[current_id] = this.composeTitle(current_id);
                    tag_string += this.composeTag(current_id);
                    page_string += this.composePage(current_id);
                }
                this.tags[current_id] += this.composeFavorite(val);
            }, this);

            // actual render
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.tags)) {
                this.el_arcmarks.innerHTML = page_string;
                this.el_tags.innerHTML = tag_string;
                this.renderFavorites();
                this.initializeTags();
            }
        },

        // insert favorite from memory into the DOM
        renderFavorites: function () {
            $A.someChild(this.el_arcmarks, function (val) {
                if (val.id) {
                    val.innerHTML = this.tags[val.id.slice(0, -5)];
                }
            }, this);
        },

        // make the tags clickable, note that jQuery handles spaces differently in the selector
        initializeTags: function (tag_el) {
            var self = this;
            if(!tag_el){
                _.each(this.tags, function (val, key) {
                    var id = '#' + key;
                    var el = $A.el(id);
                    // self.E[id]=el;
                    $(el).on("click", function () {
                        self.flip(this);
                    });
                }, this);
                var test = $A.el('#' + $A.oneKey(this.tags));
                this.flip(test);
            } else {
                $(tag_el).on("click", function () {
                    self.flip(this);
                });
            }
        },
        flip: function (tag_el) {

            // get elements
            var page_el = $A.el('#' + tag_el.id + '_page');

            // turn off
            if (this.prev_tag_el && (tag_el !== this.prev_tag_el)) {
                $A.toggleClass(this.prev_page_el, 'toggle_page_lazy');
                $A.toggleClass(this.prev_tag_el, 'toggle_tag_lazy');
            }

            // turn on
            if (this.prev_tag_el !== tag_el) {
                $A.animate(page_el, {time: 810});
                $A.toggleClass(page_el, 'toggle_page_active');
                $A.toggleClass(tag_el, 'toggle_tag_active');
            }

            // save previous
            this.prev_page_el = page_el;
            this.prev_tag_el = tag_el;
        },

        // id, favicon_local, url, title
        insertFavorite: function (obj_fav) {
            if (typeof obj_fav === 'string') {
                obj_fav = JSON.parse(obj_fav);
            }
            var tag_id = this.ns + obj_fav.tag;
            var title_el = $A.HTMLToElement(this.composeTitle(tag_id));
            var div_el = $A.HTMLToElement(this.composeFavorite(obj_fav));
            var page_el = $A.el('#' + tag_id + '_page') || this.insertTagAndPage(tag_id);
            var tag_el = $A.el('#' + tag_id);

            $A.someChild(page_el, function (iter) {
                if (iter === null) {
                    page_el.appendChild(title_el);
                    return page_el.appendChild(div_el);
                }
                if (iter.children[1] && (obj_fav.title < iter.children[1].innerHTML)) {
                    return page_el.insertBefore(div_el, iter);
                }
                if (iter === page_el.lastChild) {
                    return page_el.appendChild(div_el);
                }
            });
            this.flip(tag_el);
            return div_el;
        },

        // id
        insertTagAndPage: function (tag_id) {
            var tag_el = $A.HTMLToElement(this.composeTag(tag_id));
            var page_el = $A.HTMLToElement(this.composePage(tag_id));
            $A.insertChildById(this.el_arcmarks, page_el);
            $A.insertChildById(this.el_tags, tag_el);
            this.initializeTags(tag_el);
            return page_el;
        },

        // id
        composeArcTop: function (current_id) {
            var self = this;
            return _.template($('#arc_item-arcTop').html(), {
                id:   current_id,
                tag:  current_id.slice(self.ns.length)
            });
        },

        // id
        composeArc: function (current_id) {
            var self = this;
            return _.template($('#arc_item-arc').html(), {
                id:   current_id
            });
        },

        // id
        composeTag: function (current_id) {
            var self = this;
            return _.template($('#arc_item-tag').html(), {
                id:   current_id,
                tag:  current_id.slice(self.ns.length)
            });
        },

        // id
        composePage: function (current_id) {
            return _.template($('#arc_item-page').html(), {
                page: current_id + '_page'
            });
        },

        // id
        composeTitle: function (current_id) {
            var self = this;
            return _.template($('#arc_item-title').html(), {
                id:   current_id + '_title',
                tag:  current_id.slice(self.ns.length)
            });
        },

        // id, favicon_local, url, title
        composeFavorite: function (val) {
            return _.template($('#arc_item-arcmark').html(), {
                id:      this.ns + val.id,
                ida:     this.ns + val.id + 'a',
                idb:     this.ns + val.id + 'b',
                src:     this.path + val.favicon_local,
                href:    val.url,
                title:   val.title
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is what it renders:

[image]